# Get problems returning html data from json

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I have got jquery post function

```
jQuery('.more-button').live('click', function(eve){

    var page = jQuery(this).attr('id').replace('more-button-','');

    loaded_messages += 1;

    jQuery.post('http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/user_activity/users_picture_number', { loaded_messages : loaded_messages }, function(data) {

                    jQuery('#ajax_content').append(data.html);


            }, 'json');

});
```

My php function return json (I use Codeigniter):

```
function users_picture_number()
{

        $per_page = (int)$this->input->post('loaded_messages');

        $user_id = 3;

        $data['images_list'] = $this->user_activity_lib->users_pictures($user_id, $per_page);

        $html = $this->load->view('front_end/ajax/ajax_users_pictures', $data);

        echo json_encode(array('html' => $html));
}
```

json return to response html code but in top is shown this line `{"html":null}`

it return me : [image]

if I replace this line `$html = $this->load->view('front_end/ajax/ajax_users_pictures', $data);` with `$html = $this->load->view('front_end/ajax/ajax_users_pictures', $data, true);` it return

[image]

I try to show html which return json in  jQuery('#ajax_content')

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the html of a view in a var, the correct is indeed the second way:

```
$html = $this->load->view('front_end/ajax/ajax_users_pictures', $data, true);
```

For test you can change the method to return html and echo the content of $html.

Comment: witch echo it return html without null but if I try to add it to json through $html return null ?

Comment: add `header('Content-type: application/json');` before sending the response of you php file. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send JSON and normal HTML. In PHP your `$html` variable is empty. Check the function that is returning your value. And you have to choose if you want to transmit JSON or HTML. You set your content type to json within your ajax call, so please stick to it and dont send HTML too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem, turns out I was printing some critical characters (accented characters) without using the htmlentities function or similiar.